# How to create login name for a user in Java

Tags: javascript

Write a program that creates a login name for a user, given the user's first name, last name, and a four-digit integer as input. Output the login name, which is made up of the first five letters of the last name, followed by the first letter of the first name, and then the last two digits of the number (use the % operator). If the last name has less than five letters, then use all letters of the last name.

Ex: If the input is:

Michael Jordan 1991
the output is:

Your login name: JordaM91
Ex: If the input is:

Kanye West 2024
the output is:

Your login name: WestK24

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) | [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 1):

This covers all the use cases specified

```
const user = {
  firstName : "Michael",
  lastName : "Jordan",
  num : 1991
}

const loginName = user.lastName.slice(0,5) + user.firstName[0] + user.num.toString().slice(-2)
```

Comment: Please don't do someone else's homework unless they've demonstrated that they're actually attempted it and shown where they're stuck.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to stack overflow. Will keep your point in mind.